# Why are junk foods, which are poor for your health, certified kosher?

Tags: hechsher-certification, health-safety-shmira

Why do rabbis allow hechsherim on junk food and other foods which are clearly bad for you health? Many products are clearly not good for you such as soda pop, baked goods with trans fats, food with preservatives, processed meats, etc. yet they are certified kosher.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16041

Comment: Pastrami, corned beef, and tongue aren't the best foods for you either, but who can resist 'em?  It's not quite genetic, but close...

Answer (score 7):

My Rebbe Rav Shmuel Dishon (mashgiach ruchni Karlin Stolin) once asked us how do we think Kashrus organizations are allowed to issue "kosher" status on things that are damaging to the human body (unhealthy foods etc.) ?

We didn't know. So he answered, that all foods can be good in measure. Sugar can be good sprinkled here and there. Even a fattening sugary cheesecake can be a kosher treat at the right time and place. However, overindulgence is a choice. It is overindulgence that makes some foods dangerous. That's the consumer's business, not the Kashrus industry's business to regulate. The individual hechsher is only able to determine if the ingredients fit the rules of Kosher foods permitted by the Torah for a Jew to eat.

Comment: Rambam Hilchos Deios 4:9 יש מאכלות שהם רעים ביותר עד מאד וראוי לאדם שלא לאוכלן לעולם

Comment: I'm not saying that Rambam said anything is assur. Just that he seems to disagree with your Rebbe's claim "that all foods can be good in measure".

Comment: @Alex, "proper", not forbidden. Also, the small list contains items like mushrooms. The Gemara tells us that Shmuel counted mushrooms among his favorite foods. Also, Rambam's list contains stale, rotten, and severely salted and old meats/fish. Kashrus certifies ingredients, not if you left the food out to age or rot.

Comment: @Alex Rambam seems to be speaking exclusively from a health perspective. However, it may be a good idea to allow someone to eat an unhealthy food (that they like very much) to celebrate some important achievement. The spiritual positive reinforcement, may outweigh the temporary health concern. Rambam may agree to this too. So, all foods may be good in proper measure. This excludes a dangerous food which would be forbidden.

Comment: That's the next category ויש מאכלות שהן רעים אבל אינן כמו הראשונים לרוע לפיכך ראוי לאדם שלא לאכול מהן אלא מעט ואחר ימים הרבה ולא ירגיל עצמו להיות מזונו מהם או לאוכלן עם מזונו תמיד

Comment: @ no its not. Even the first category may have a use. Its just that he advises "proper to not eat at all". He doesn't forbid. BTW, what food relevant to the OP is on the Rambam's list of "proper not to eat at all"? soda pop, danishes, hot dogs? What food would you say the Rambam includes under that category that the OP is discussing? If there isn't one, then its moot.

Comment: The point is that Rambam knew how to say that certain things can be eaten on rare (special?) occasions yet he still said that certain things should never be eaten.

Comment: This is a good, concise answer that I think defines the role of the kashrut industry and hechsherim. Essentially, it states that their sole responsibility is to verify the kosher status of the food. They don't evaluate the effect of the food's ingredients. It would be impossible to do so, as each person's metabolism and desires are different. My grandparents ate *gribenes* and shmaltz constantly yet lived through their mid 90's. For most people, these foods are "poison", but, various people can tolerate these foods. The entire diet is really the issue, not just one food item.

Answer (score 1):

kosher certification can be given for anything that includes only kosher ingredients.

So an item that includes anything like not kosher animals, milk and meat together, or anything else that's not kosher, those products will not receive a hechsher.

But, any product that has all kosher ingredients, why should it not be kosher (as long as you don't mix milk and meat..)? Kashrus does not depend on health. There are many healthy foods that are not kosher, and so too there are many non healthy foods that are kosher.

Comment: ..."so too there are many non healthy foods that are kosher."  You just don't get it.  The whole point is that no certification organization in light of the fact that very many "kosher" items are NOT healthy, and people and the producers of the non healthy foods are violating shomer ha goof, the Rabbis shoud NOT accept a payment on foods that are detrimental for your health. It is totally hypocritical. With all the natural food hashem gave us those companies that make garbage foods should be banned.

Comment: @herman it's not hypocritical. It's just honesty. The food is kosher. Also the food shouldn't be eaten. A rabbi should tell you both true statements. Rabbis shouldn't lie

Comment: @herman is the food kosher? Yes. Therefore the Rabbi gave the hechsher. If you don't want to eat it, then don't. But those that want to enjoy some junk food, why deprive them. I see you have a strong opinion on healthy foods, but not everyone does, and you can't say that it's against halacha to have it.