# Question about Leviticus 11:43

Tags: animals, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, eating, parashat-shemini

The verse in Leviticus 11:43 speaks about becoming unclean by eating "unclean" animals.

> You shall not make yourselves abominable with any creeping creature that creeps, and you shall not defile yourselves with them, that you should become unclean through them.

How can one who ate unclean animal can get cleansed/purified from that eating (the eating itself, I am not talking about the uncleanness that comes by touching)? Will he be forever unclean?

Does this type of uncleanness prohibit him from eating sacrifices or entering the temple?

Comment: Great question, Kapandaria! I think you will find several good answers here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119351/tikkun-for-timtum-halev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verse refers to negative spiritual effects of eating non-kosher food. This does not equal the ritual uncleanliness that forbids entering the Temple, etc. described in other verses.

As with all sins, the primary cleansing process is through repentance. For individual cases, it is wise to consult a rabbi for specific advice.